# Is it faster to recreate an object or store it in a session variable?

Tags: php, performance, object, session-variables

Sorry if this seems obvious to the non-noob.  Is it faster to:

- Recreate an object instance each time someone goes to a page during a session

or

- Store the object instance in a session variable when it first gets created, then always grab it from there when the page is accessed again

I'm not sure if this will turn out to be a "How long is a piece of string?" sort of question, but if it does, then perhaps you could let me know what factors are involved in making the decision?

Comment: @molf, I'm completely new to this and it took me two days of fiddling to get XAMPP to work. I want to learn how to do benchmarking soon,  but I'm not quite ready to spend another few days working out how that is done.  Go easy on the noob!  Besides, people here are telling me not just what, but *why*.  I won't find that out from benchmarking.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you're unsure how to do benchmarking then I think you don't need to worry about this kind of performance yet.

Comment: @molf, good point, but I want to start out the right way so that I don't learn bad habits.

Answer (score 4):

Session data is stored as text, not binary data so somewhere behind the scenes when you toss it into the session the object is recreated anyway. It's probably a little bit slower than initializing it yourself since it has to do some string parsing but I doubt it's much to worry about. In short, it probably doesn't make a difference either way.

Comment: it can also be faster as deserializing places the contents directly into properties without calling a constructor. It could call a __wake() method, though. In the end performance is barely an argument here, more about application design.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly depends on how much logic is done, when the object is created. You should do some benchmarks with both variations.

Answer (score 0):

Without measuring it, i'd say storing and retrieving should most times be faster.
For recreating objects you have to call possibly multiple constructors, etc, whereas retrieving shouldn't invoke any function calls.

Answer (score 0):

It obviously depends on what fields you have in object, how many of them and how they are populated. Instantion of an object occurs every time you load a page anyway, so it's the matter of fields and their sources.

Comment: Remember that PHP doesn't have some common memory to store instances between requests like ASP.NET has. Objects are serialized and deserialized in text, so the instance is recreated every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just be wary of trying too hard to optimise this.  Bear in mind that storing items in session can be heavy, particularly if your site is high traffic.

Also, I've seen a lot of people create an object, which accesses a database and loads it's attributes.  This then gets stored in session, updated on postback and then saved back to teh database.

This is fine, but it makes for difficult concurrency checking - say your object has a timestamp of the last time saved - if you reload it each time prior to saving, you can easily check if the timestamp has changed since the last load, in which case you may need to stop the save from going ahead.

Either way, the difference is not going to be huge.